# Javascript issue with rendering updated chart in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a chart, when I use the code here it renders fine: http://jsfiddle.net/skzBt/1/. But the code below doesn't work.

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/dh");

var buffer = [['1', [0]], ['2', [0]], ['3', [0]], ['4', [0]]];
var data = [];

var w = 500;
var h = 300;
var barPadding = 1;

var chart = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
//.attr("class", "chart");
.attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

function draw() {
    chart.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("svg:rect").attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (w / data.length);
}).attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d * 4);
}).attr("width", w / data.length - barPadding).attr("height", function(d) {
    return d * 4;
}).attr("fill", function(d) {
    return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
});

chart.selectAll("text").data(data).enter().append("svg:text").text(function(d) {
    return d;
}).attr("text-anchor", "middle").attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (w / data.length) + (w / data.length - barPadding) / 2;
}).attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d * 4) + 14;
}).attr("font-family", "sans-serif").attr("font-size", "11px").attr("fill", "white");

};


//draw();     
ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    data.length = 0;
    var distances = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    console.log(distances);
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        if (buffer[i][0] == distances.miles) {
            buffer[i][1][0]++; //add the new miles to the total from previous iteration
        }
    }
    console.log(buffer);

    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        data.push(buffer[i][1][0]);
        console.log(data);
        draw(); //redraw the graph
    }
}
```

I think it has to do something with data.length = 0;, as without it the graph renders BUT adds extra columns each item. I want the graph to be redrawn each time the array data is updated. I know that data is getting the updated with the incremented values.

I'm really confused and stuck here and would really appreciate help please.

Thanks

EDIT:

After more testing the function draw() works, I can see values in the 'data' array incrementing correctly and what seem to happen is that the function is only called once as it plots the values only once and then stops.

Comment: What does `console.log(distances);` yield?

Comment: Hi it yields:({miles:3}) it will return a range from 1-4 as the value of miles

Comment: What would it be if there was more than one mileage in the data?

Comment: it returns these one at a time and these are then inserted to and incremented into the buffer array. Then the dataset gets these new updated values to plot. I then clean out the dataset array and repeat the process again, so the chart is constantly been redrawn.

Comment: That would only make sense if there was something in the returned data to indicate the index of the graph-point that the mileage relates to. Otherwise, how do you tie up new mileage with the corresponding old mileage?

Comment: I'm completely redrawing the chart each time the data array is updated the newly incremented values from the buffer array. So I don't need to worry about indexing or trying to create a seam with the older data.

Comment: Whatever you subsequently do with the data, you need to know which element of the buffer is to be incremented. Nothing client-side will compensate for the absence of a handle in the data returned from the server. I think this is why you are having a problem with it.

Comment: The right element of the buffer does get incremented correctly. So each time the draw function gets the dataset values they are correctly incremented with the relevant values. I've used another derivation of draw() function which rendered the graph. Its this draw() function that doesn't render it, possibly because of setting data.length = 0; at each time after drawing the chart.

Comment: Ah, then you're treating the data differently from the "cumulative miles" in your earlier question. This is now a frequency chart.

Comment: Yes....apologies for not being clearer. I'm looking at the number of times a range of miles occurs.

Comment: In that case you seem to be along the right lines with handling the data, though it's not necessary to use a buffer; you can increment the `data` values directly. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify the .onmessage handler as follows :

```
var data = [0, 0, 0, 0];
...
ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var distances = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    data[distances.miles-1]++;
    draw();
}
```

All other issues must be inside the `draw()` function. I'm afraid I'm not an expert in **d3** so you'll have to plug away at that. The extensive [API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference) documentation will be your best friend.

Comment: Hi I tried the above and it gave me a 405 error; method not allowed. Thanks

Comment: The suggested code does nothing more than update the `data` array and couldn't possibly provoke an HTTP error. It must have arisen from something else you were trying.